# ¿Cómo detectar errores async/await?

Tags: javascript, json

Tengo un JSON tal que así :

```
{
"product": "BMW",
"model": "X5",
"age": 2017
}
```

Si usase promesas podría hacer esto para leer los datos y crear un objeto con esos valores

```
let d = fetch('api.json').then((e) => {
   e.json().then((e) => {
       let c = new Car(e.product, e.model, e.age)
   }).catch(err => alert(err))
}).catch(err => alert(err))
```

Como estoy usando `.then` puedo usar `.catch` para detectar errores

Pero si hiciese este mismo código con async / await quedaría así:

```
async function d() {
    let d = await fetch('api.json');
    d = await d.json()

    let c = new Car(d.product, d.model, d.age)
}
d()
```

¿Cómo puedo detectar errores usando este método?

Comment: dentro de la funcion, usa un bloque try/catch que abarque las lineas que hacen la peticion fetch y que administran la respuesta https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/try...catch

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Usa un bloque try/catch de toda la vida, dentro del try va el codigo que asumes puede tener un error, y el bloque catch captura dicho error:

```
async function getPosts(){
  try {
    let res = await fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts')
    res = await res.json()
    console.log(res)
  } catch (err) {
    console.log('error!!!' + err)
  }
}

getPosts()
```

Comment: Muchas gracias, no había caído en que la solución podría ser algo tan simple... 

Comment: @Roberto quizas al ser la async/await un concepto de nivel medio/avanzado asumías que la solución era otra, nuestro cerebro nos engaña jaja

Comment: @Roberto esa es la ventaja de async/await, hace el código más legible pudiendo detectar errores como lo harías con una función normal.